# Updating Object Property by calling module code - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I pass  an object (Check Box) from the worksheet code to a module to update its properties (the value and the backcolor).

```
Dim Range1 As Range
Set Range1 = Range("K2")
Dim ChkBox1 As Object
Set ChkBox1 = CheckBox1
```

The passing code is:

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    SetGreen R1:=Range1, C1:=ChkBox1
Else
    SetRed R1:=Range1, C1:=ChkBox1
End If
```

So if the checkbox is ticked, set the backcolor to green , and if it's not checked, set it to red.

The called procedure code for setting to red is:

```
Sub SetRed(ByVal R1 As Range, ByVal C1 As Object)
    R1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    With C1
        .BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Value = False
    End With
End Sub
```

The properties (value and backcolor) do not update in this module until the code has returned to the calling procedure and this procedure exits. The Interior color of the cell updates immediately within the called procedure though. Why don't the check box properties update immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Excel are you using? In 2010 I can see the control update whilst in the called routine and the property values are altered accordingly.

Comment: I don't have 2007 here to test so will have to do that later, pending other responses. Are you stepping through the code and watching the UI or testing with debug.print statements? Also, what SP level do you have your copy of Office patched to?

Comment: I've stepped through the code and watched the control which is in a cell. When stepping through the code, the control properties and the cell colour update immediately but when running the code only the cell colour updates immediately and the control properties (colour and value) only update after a message box to a user is okayed in the calling procedure.

Comment: OK, tested with msgbox in 2010 and the control updates before the message appears. In 2007 if you add `Application.Screenupdating = True` before the message box line does the control update?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Tried 'Application.Screenupdating = True' but the CheckBox control still didn't update colour or value until after the Msgbox was okayed in the calling procedure.

Comment: I've tested in 2007 (version 12.0.6665.5003 SP3) and can't reproduce the issue unless screenupdating is still off.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your efforts, I appreciate it. Will continue to look at why this may be happening and if I find a solution I'll post it.